# Scraping AliExpress : Data Attribute doesn't load until Inspect Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-scraping, puppeteer, cheerio

I'm trying to scrape some information on a product on Aliexpress.com

Here is a sample product i tried : 
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32905045358.html?spm=2114.search0104.3.9.55e81bfaYkNYa0&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0%2Csearchweb201602_9_10065_10068_319_10546_10059_10884_317_10548_10887_10696_321_322_10084_453_10083_454_10103_10618_10307_537_536%2Csearchweb201603_52%2CppcSwitch_0&algo_expid=b2cb9169-93e1-4d1d-a2a9-01caee37e0b4-1&algo_pvid=b2cb9169-93e1-4d1d-a2a9-01caee37e0b4

What I want : 
To get data-spm-anchor-id attribute from each of the variant images.

Problem : It doesn't load until I try to inspect element manually

Try to get attribute as soon as page is done loading :

```
document.querySelector('.sku-property-image').querySelector('img')
```

result :

```
<img src="https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1HAk8UgHqK1RjSZFkq6x.WFXaB/Boruto-Naruto-Hoodies-Jacket-Men-3D-Hoodie-Akatsuki-Coat-Uchiha-Itach-Cosplay-Costume-Kakashi-Hoodies-Sweatshirts.jpg_50x50.jpg" title="2">
```

Inspect element to see if data-spm exists :

[image]

and then run the query again on console and you will see this :

```
<img src="https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1HAk8UgHqK1RjSZFkq6x.WFXaB/Boruto-Naruto-Hoodies-Jacket-Men-3D-Hoodie-Akatsuki-Coat-Uchiha-Itach-Cosplay-Costume-Kakashi-Hoodies-Sweatshirts.jpg_50x50.jpg" title="2" data-spm-anchor-id="a2g0o.detail.1000016.i1.570f6bf9tarSlz">
```

the data-spm-anchor-id attr suddenly appears after inspecting the element

how do i get this programattically via puppeteer or cheerio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That attribute is being loaded when you click that image. So basically you need to click each image and get the attribute. You can do something like this:

```js
var images = await page.$$(".sku-property-image");
for(let image of images) {
  await image.click();
  //Wait for the attribute to be loaded.
  await page.waitFor(image => image.querySelector("img").getAttribute("data-spm-anchor-id"), {}, image);
  console.log(await page.evaluate(image => image.querySelector("img").getAttribute("data-spm-anchor-id"), image));
}
```